# Image need to resize by half based upon first div image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two different type of image with various sizes inside the two div tags. I need to resize the 2nd div image size by half of first div image.

```css
.first-div img {
  width:500px; //this img size may be random
}
.second-div img {
  width:250px;//need to resize the img half of first-div image
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/68/8e/99688e0cebdb1f8bde066b9bbf969003.jpg" width="" />
</div>

<div class="second-div">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/19/15/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg" width="" />
</div>
```

For example if the first div image size 200 and the second div image size 100. anyone help me to achieve this.

Comment: which size? width or height?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @brk width need to resize by half in second div based on first div img

Comment: @Jtbs. Can use js,jquery,css .

Comment: In that case,  you can do `$('.second-div img').width($('.first-div img').width()/2)`

Comment: not working yar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Jquery`

```js
$('.second-div img').width($('.first-div img').width()/2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-div">
 <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/68/8e/99688e0cebdb1f8bde066b9bbf969003.jpg" width="" />
</div>

<div class="second-div">
 <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/19/15/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg" width="" />
</div>
```

You can achieve this by using `css variables`

```css
:root {
    --main-width: 500px; 
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
}
.first-div img {
  width:var(--main-width); 
}
.second-div img {
  width:calc(var(--main-width)/2);
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
 <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/68/8e/99688e0cebdb1f8bde066b9bbf969003.jpg" width="" />
</div>

<div class="second-div">
 <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/19/15/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg" width="" />
</div>
```

Comment: can set root width 100%?

Comment: @John Yes, ofcrse

Comment: prob with this site only between 600*600 mm and 300*600 mm in show all category http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/product/view/Homogeneous

Comment: @John you said about `width`. what is really needed on this site ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166934/discussion-between-john-and-anuresh).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using jQuery like this:

```
 var img = new Image();

 img.onload = function() {
      alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
      var width = this.width;
      $('.second-div img').css('width',width/2);
 }
 var url = $('.first-div').find('img').attr("src"); // get dynamically url image
 img.src = url;

  or

 img.src = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/99/68/8e/99688e0cebdb1f8bde066b9bbf969003.jpg';//image_path_of_first_div_image;
```

Here you get width and height of image dynamically by passing image URL.

Comment: can't load load the image src within script.

Comment: Okay, @John Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes. But not loading the image within a script

Comment: How are you passing image URL in JavaScript?

Comment: var url = $('.first-div').find('img').attr("src"); and pass this url.

Comment: http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/product/view/Homogeneous this is my website. and this what I am trying to achieve https://ibb.co/jok5ec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166936/discussion-between-john-and-gufran-hasan).

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do

`$('.second-div img').width($('.first-div img').width()/2)`